# html SELECT list from mysql with PhP loop for the list

Tags: php

```html
 <tr>
            <td>Select Type</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><select name="type" id="type">
      <option value="" selected>Select hos-type</option>
  <?php

$sql = "select * from h_type";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($res) ) 
{
 $no = $rec['no'];
 $type = $rec['type'];
 $type = '';
 $selected = '';
 if ($type == $no)
 $selected = 'Selected';
 echo "<option value='$no' $selected> $type </option> ";
 
}

?>      
      </select></td>
         </tr>
         
         <tr>
         <td></br></br></td>
           <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
           <td><input type="reset"></td>
         </tr>
        </table><br><br>
       </td>
     </form>
   </tr>
</table>

<?php
// Get values from form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$name = stripslashes($name);
$address = stripslashes($address);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($address);



//declare in the order variable
/*$result = mysql_query($sql); //order executes
if($result)
{
 echo("Input data is succeed");
}
else
{
 echo("Input data is fail");
}*/
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}

$sql="INSERT INTO hospitals (name, address, email, file_name, file_type, file_size, content, no_h_type)
VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$email', '$fileName', '$fileType', '$fileSize', '$content', '$no')";

mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, query failed'); 


echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
 echo("Input data is succeed");

} 
?>
```

I am writing a code for back-end (admin); the admin should fill in the form and there is a SELECT list each row in it have a no (i.e. no is like ID) when press Submit and go back to the database to see the result i found that everything is right EXCEPT the no that appears from the SELECT list it just one number even if i select different option it STOP at certain no and does not change with the options that i select (i don't know if my loop is right or wrong because there is no bugs or error appear with me
and i need help..!

Comment: Can you break up your issue into sentences please?

Comment: Hard to say anything decent about this, is the `no` you are talking about the primary key in the table? Also does it automatically increment?

Comment: You're probably using the **SAME** `name=` for all of your `<select>` boxes. if they're all being sent back when the form submits, then each should have a unique name, or use php's `name="foo[]"` array hack.

Comment: the no is a primary key in h_type table and automatically increment

Comment: sorry but after submit it will be a foreign key in another table and should appears there in different table

Comment: i tried to make a different name now but nothing change  my problem is that each row in the select list have a no or id after choosing what option i want and submit everything is ok

Comment: but when going back to the database i found that only one id is work for all options and the rest of ids is nothing means it is stop only in a certain no and does not change if i choose any other one

Comment: and i have two tables the ( select list only)  will come from table ; and after submit the information that i entered should be saved in the second table

Comment: and the second table will contain the info and the no or id of the option that i already choose the relation between them is the no

Comment: i did many ways but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
 <tr>
            <td>Select Type</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><select name="type" id="type">
      <option value="" selected>Select hos-type</option>
<?php
$sql_type = "select * from h_type";
$res_type = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_type); // $conn (page conn.php - contain the code for the connection from database)

while ($rec_type = mysqli_fetch_array($res_type,MYSQLI_BOTH) ) 
{
 $no = $rec_type['no'];
 $type_name = $rec_type['type'];
 $type = '';
 $selected = '';
 if ($type == $no)
 $selected = 'Selected';
 echo "<option value='$no' $selected> $type_name </option> ";
}

?>      
      </select></td>
         </tr>
         
         <tr>
         <td></br></br></td>
           <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
           <td><input type="reset"></td>
         </tr>
        </table><br><br>
       </td>
     </form>
   </tr>
</table>

<?php
// Get values from form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name     = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email     = $_POST['email'];
$type      = $_POST['type']; // here is the identification for the type var..

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)

$name = stripslashes($name);
$address = stripslashes($address);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name); // the $conn to connect with the database
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $address); //

//declare in the order variable

}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}

$sql="INSERT INTO hospitals (name, address, email, file_name, file_type, file_size, content, no_h_type)
VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$email', '$fileName', '$fileType', '$fileSize', '$content', '$type')";

if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) // the connection with the database and calling the var $sql
{
echo("Input data is succeed");
}
else

echo 'Error:'. mysql_error();

} 
?>
```

Comment: there is little modification i found the problem and here is the solution it's work with me perfectly. thanks for trying to help.